# Alternate method to solve this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

> $$
> \int \! \sqrt{\frac{x}{x^3 - a^3}} \, dx
> $$

I solved this integral by substitution method by taking $t= x^{3/2}$. Is there any other method to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please do not enclose mathematical formulas in pictures, which are furthermore linked to somewhere. Just type them here using mathjax, see also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . So please edit and insert here the code for the integral... (Well somebody did it in this second...)

Comment: two remarks: could you write down the answer and your proof? Why do you need a second way to compute this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: substitute
$$ x=a\sec ^\frac{2}{3} \theta$$